# Pulling in types for use in a .d.ts file with declare module without making it a module file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I am attempting to write a type declaration for an NPM package (or more specifically an untyped directory within a package) my project depends on.

The package itself is `react-big-calendar` and it doesn't bundle its own types, however there is `@types/react-big-calendar` which provides types for the main package, but not for the `react-big-calendar/lib/addons/dragAndDrop` "sub-package" it has in itself.

The above gets me working `import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar'` which is great, and I want to also get working `import withDragAndDrop from 'react-big-calendar/lib/addons/dragAndDrop'` so I figured I'd just `declare module` my way there.

I cannot place the `declare module` statement in any TSX file, because it has to be in its own file which is not an ES module, but it also cannot be an import+export free TS file, because I am also using CRA which enforces `isolatedModules` and so disallows non-module TS/X files.

I can and should place it in a `.d.ts` file, like this:

```
declare module 'react-big-calendar/lib/addons/dragAndDrop' {
  function withDragAndDrop(calendar: any): any;
  export = withDragAndDrop;
}
```

This looks fine, but is not much of an improvement typing-wise. The function I am looking to type basically takes a React component and returns it with some extra props. But even to just type is as a function which takes the specific `BigCalendar` component and returns it is a problem, because I cannot use an `import` statement (to pull in the component type) in the `d.ts` file. If I do, it turns into a module file and that breaks the `declare module` statement.

I am looking for something like this:

```
declare module 'react-big-calendar/lib/addons/dragAndDrop' {
  function withDragAndDrop(calendar: BigCalendar): typeof BigCalendar & {
    props: {
      extraProp1: string;
      // …
      extraPropN: string;
    }
  };
  export = withDragAndDrop;
}
```

With that I should be able to use the HOC like this: `const DragAndDropCalendar = withDragAndDrop(BigCalendar);` followed by `<DragAndDropCalendar originalProp={value} extraProp1={value} />`.

The thing that is missing is pulling in the types to the `.d.ts` file in a way which doesn't turn it into a module breaking the `declare module` statement stripping me of types, bringing me to square one again.

What options do I have there? I tried to use `require` but that returns `any` and I couldn't figure out if `<reference` is the right tool here or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to import the original component types (React Big Calendar in this case, but the solution is generic) in the typings (which in this case are for the RBC drag and drop addon).

`withDragAndDrop.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'react-big-calendar/lib/addons/dragAndDrop' {
    import BigCalendar, { BigCalendarProps, Event } from 'react-big-calendar';

    type withDragAndDropProps<TEvent> = {
        onEventDrop: (args: { event: TEvent, start: stringOrDate, end: stringOrDate, allDay: boolean }) => void;
        onEventResize: (args: { event: TEvent, start: stringOrDate, end: stringOrDate, allDay: boolean }) => void;
    };

    declare class DragAndDropCalendar<TEvent extends Event = Event, TResource extends object = object>
        extends React.Component<BigCalendarProps<TEvent, TResource> & withDragAndDropProps<TEvent>>, {}

    function withDragAndDrop(calendar: typeof BigCalendar): typeof DragAndDropCalendar;
    export = withDragAndDrop;
};
```

Usage:

```
import withDragAndDrop from 'react-big-calendar/lib/addons/dragAndDrop';
import "react-big-calendar/lib/addons/dragAndDrop/styles.css";
const DragAndDropCalendar = withDragAndDrop(BigCalendar);

// TSX:
<DragAndDropCalendar<MyEvent>  … onEventDrop onEventResize />
```